# Valores null a un php al pasar datos desde javascript

Tags: javascript, php, post

Tengo valores que se obtienen desde un datatable y son almacenados en variables, las cuales quiero pasar a través de POST a php, sin embargo da el error `Undefined index`, a pesar de ver en consola que las variables tienen un valor asignado.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#tablaUnidades td button');
 
  allButtons.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault();
 
        var allCells = elem.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('td');

      codigo = allCells[0].textContent;
      deslar = allCells[1].textContent;
      descor = allCells[2].textContent;
      opcion = allCells[3].textContent; 

      console.log(codigo, deslar, descor, opcion);

 fetch('bd/crud_unidades.php',{
    method: "POST",
    data: {codigo: codigo, deslar: deslar, descor: descor, opcion: opcion}
   })
        .then(res=>res.text())
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
    }) 
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tablaUnidades" width="100%" cellspacing="0" method="post">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>CODIGO</th>
  <th>DESCRIPCIÓN LARGA</th>
  <th>DESCRIPCIÓN CORTA</th>
  <th>ACCIÓN</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
<td id="codigo"> value 1</td>
  <td id="deslar"> value 2</td>
   <td id="descor">value 3</td>
     <td><button class='btn btn-primary btnVER' id="VER" name="VER"> Click Me</button></a></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
   </table>
```

crud_unidades.php:

```
<?php

 $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
 $deslar = $_POST['deslar'];
 $descor = $_POST['descor'];
 $opcion = $_POST['opcion'];

 echo var_dump($codigo);

?>
```

No logro enviar las variables en javascript al php para luego poder usarlas en una consulta en mi base de datos. Las variables en php al poner var_dump devuelven NULL

Comment: y aintentaste con form data ? var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

así se debe hacer para que funcione son pequeños cambios

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#tablaUnidades td button');
 
  allButtons.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault();
 
        var allCells = elem.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('td');


      let codigo = allCells[0].textContent;
      let deslar = allCells[1].textContent;
      let descor = allCells[2].textContent;
      let opcion = allCells[3].textContent; 

     
    var formData = new FormData;
    var arr = {'codigo': codigo, 'deslar': deslar, 'descor': descor, 'opcion': opcion};
     Object.entries(arr).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(key,value);
      });
   
 fetch('bd/crud_unidades.php',{
    method: "POST",
    cors: "CROS",
    body: formData,
   })
        .then(res=>res.text())
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
    }) 
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tablaUnidades" width="100%" cellspacing="0" method="post">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>CODIGO</th>
  <th>DESCRIPCIÓN LARGA</th>
  <th>DESCRIPCIÓN CORTA</th>
  <th>ACCIÓN</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
<td id="codigo"> value 1</td>
  <td id="deslar"> value 2</td>
   <td id="descor">value 3</td>
     <td><button class='btn btn-primary btnVER' id="VER" name="VER"> Click Me</button></a></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió bastante bien

Answer (score 1):

En vez de `data` utiliza `body` y `JSON.parse`, añadele tambien de paso un `header` especifico para que reconozca el formato:

```
fetch('bd/crud_unidades.php', {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({codigo: codigo, deslar: deslar, descor: descor, opcion: opcion}),
    headers: {
       'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
  })
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
});
```

`body` será el cuerpo de los datos que vas a enviar, el body puede ser enviado en multiples formatos y dependera deacuerdo al tipo especificado en los `headers` en este caso un `json`, tambien hay que decir que para poder enviar los datos debemos primero serializarlos, esto lo hacemos con `JSON.stringify`.